# Is there a way to backup my WSL Ubuntu 20.04 environment and restore it on my Ubuntu 20.04 system?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Is there a way to backup my WSL ubuntu 20.04 environment and restore it on my Ibuntu 20.04 system?

I'm currently working through WSL but I think I am approaching the time when I have to move to a plain Linux system.

How can I back up all my installed services and files to the new system?

Answer (score 2):

It might not be a 1-1 match, but its a little easier on linux due to 'everything being a file'. I haven't quite gotten around to figuring out how to back up snap based software. I have an [old answer here](https://serverfault.com/questions/540885/how-do-i-duplicate-a-server/540888#540888) that needs a few updates, but essentially

On Ubuntu or debian,[use dpkg --get-selections to dump out a list of installed packages, and install them with dpkg --set-selections](https://serverfault.com/questions/540885/how-do-i-duplicate-a-server/540888#540888).

I've not quite needed to do this with snaps.

This is untested but you can use `snap list` to list out snaps. You can then `snap save` each snap to make a snapshot  [`snap export-snapshot` then `snap import-snapshot`](https://snap%20export-snapshot) should backup and restore specific snaps

Create the same users as the source system if necessary - `cat /etc/passwd` should list them out, and you can check with diff to see if the two lists are identical.

Then use rsync to duplicate your `/etc/` folder for settings, various `/home/` folders for users (and check permissions here) and other folders like `/var/www/`. Test, make sure everything's there and working, and starting up as needed, and you're done. Takes me less time than to set up a fresh server.

If you're using another method, you need to make sure the permissions and attributes are correct

That should cover your entire environment.

Comment: i basically do not have any snap install, just a server and packages related to this type of thing like php, nginx (configs) mysql db and rest. So you think that this type of approach can help to achieve the result?

Comment: And the reason why i'm asking is that the plain ubuntu has their own gnome UI wrap, can that be a problem when I will try to applying the backup archive to the fresh desktop system?

Comment: How do you handle things like `/etc/passwd`?  Overwriting the "real" Ubuntu's users and groups with those that were backed up from WSL's `/etc` (which is based on Ubuntu *Server*) seems like a recipe for disaster, right?

Comment: That's why I create new accounts - when I do this I mainly copy over specific folders n /etc/ as needed

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco that's the scenario I usually do it with. I do think depending on the db there's specific tools to back up. I will give it a think and update

Answer (score 1):

While (most) everything in [@JourneymanGeek's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1732574/167207) is correct, I think I'd look at it a bit differently.  I'd say it's worth a try, but you might need to make multiple attempts to 'get it just right.'

There are a few things that some users do in WSL that will end up causing problems in "real" Ubuntu.  I'll call some of these out below.

Backing up a WSL2 Ubuntu distribution and restoring it a to "real" Ubuntu installation is going to involve several steps:

- Will you be dual-booting Ubuntu with Windows or replacing the Windows installation entirely?  If dual-booting, then you can use a folder on the Windows drive to hold any files you need to transfer.  Otherwise, you'll need to move them to something like a USB drive.
- You *could* potentially use `rsync` directly if dual-booting, but you'll need to access the WSL2 `ext4.vhdx` virtual disk in Ubuntu.  This capability isn't installed by default, so you'll need to find a solution to that -- If you want to use `rsync`, refer to [this Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/295155/1165986) question.
- I'd probably just `tar` any files you need to transfer, but make sure you do so as `sudo`/root so that permissions and ownership are preserved (or use the appropriate `tar` flags if using a non-root user).
- Identify the packages you have installed under WSL2/Ubuntu, as JG points out in the linked answer.  Save that to a file for transfer.

  *Remove* any WSL-specific packages like `wslu`.  These can cause issues on "real" Ubuntu (although I can't remember the question I came across with this issue at the moment).
- `tar` your user's `/home/username`.  This is probably the most straightforward to transfer, although remove any "WSL-specific" changes you have made to your shell startup (e.g. `~/.bashrc`).

  For instance, since WSL doesn't have `systemctl enable`, it's common to start a service in the user `~/.bashrc`.  You should revert that and plan to use Systemd under the real installation.
- `tar` your `/etc` directory, but use extreme caution when restoring to the "real" Ubuntu.  This is the area most likely to cause issues for several reasons:

  - First, this may or may not be a problem, but the WSL Ubuntu distribution is based on Ubuntu *Server*.  You'll probably be installing Ubuntu *Desktop*.  The `/etc` configuration is likely to be quite different between two.  I can't point directly at any problems with restoring a "server" configuration on top of a newly installed "desktop" one, but I also don't know that it's a tested or supported scenario.  You *may* end up overwriting some "desktop-specific" configuration with the more "minimal" server config.
  - More significantly, if you've ever tried to enable Systemd on WSL, I would probably just ignore (`tar --exclude-from`) anything in `/etc/systemd` and `/etc/tmpfiles.d`.  The changes you made (or the enablement script) in order to make things work on WSL are almost certainly going to break things on a real Ubuntu installation.
  - In addition, exclude the following from your `/etc` tarball:

    - `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/group`, and `/etc/shadow`.  These will be created by the Ubuntu installation itself (including your default user) or by the packages you install.  If you overwrite the Ubuntu Desktop installed versions of those files with your WSL2 copy, things will break.
    - `/etc/fstab`, as you don't want to overwrite that of the physical machine's configuration.
    - `/etc/resolv.conf`, since WSL configures this to use the Windows host resolver
    - `/etc/hosts`, which is also generated by WSL with internal Windows/WSL names.

  There may be others -- These are just the ones I can think of that will cause problems if you try to move them from WSL to a real physical machine.
- As @JG said, back up any other directories where you might have working files, like specific directories under `/var/`.

Comment: Will you be dual-booting Ubuntu with Windows or replacing the Windows installation entirely? Yes, I'm thinking to switch to Ubuntu entirely.

Comment: `For instance, since WSL doesn't have systemctl enable, it's common to start a service in the user ~/.bashrc. You should revert that and plan to use Systemd under the real installation.` how can i do that, i'm not so established linux user yet :)

Comment: I guess I'm not the only one will look this question.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco Either edit your `~/.bashrc` (and other startup files) to remove any special "customizations" done for WSL or just copy over the "non-WSL" specific changes to your new user's config manually.